# Function template taking function template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++-concepts

I'm learning concepts and templates. I'm trying to make a function template that will call another function template. Currently it works with lambda but not with a normal function.

```
// This also works with lambda but not the normal function:
//void callFunc(std::regular_invocable<T> auto invocable)

template<typename T>
void callFunc(auto invocable)
{
    invocable(T(5));
}

// Doesn't work, whether I use "T" or "auto"
//template<typename T>
void testFuncToPass(const auto& a)
{
    std::cout << a << " CALLED\n";
}

//...

auto lambda = [](const auto& a){std::cout << a << " CALLED\n";};

//callFunc<int>(testFuncToPass); // ERROR
callFunc<int>([](const auto& a){std::cout << a << " CALLED\n";});
callFunc<int>(lambda);
```

It says: "error : no matching function for call to 'callFunc'. candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'invocable:auto'"

Is what I'm trying to do doable? I also tried to use template template parameter but seems that only works for types, not for functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are under the impression that

```
auto lambda = [](const auto& a){std::cout << a << " CALLED\n";};
```

is equivalent to

```
template<typename T>
void lambda(const T& a) { std::cout << a << " CALLED\n"; }
```

But it's not. It's actually equivalent to:

```
struct SomeType {
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(const T& a) const { std::cout << a << " CALLED\n"; }
};
SomeType lambda;
```

Fun fact: If your lambda captures values and/or references, they become private members of that struct, and marking the lambda as mutable simply removes the `const`. Lambdas are effectively just syntactic sugar on top of functors.

> Is what I'm trying to do doable?

Unfortunately not as of the current standard. It is possible to accept a templated type as an argument (via some funky-looking syntax), but function templates are still off the table at the moment.

You pretty much have to declare a struct or a class with a templated `operator()` like in my example, or wrap them in a lambda:

```
callFunc<int>([](auto const& a){testFuncToPass(a);});
```